# Fill one Datagridview's Column by a List

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that's bounded to a dataBase (I have the bindingSource and the bindingNavigator)

so if I want to display all the table (livre in my case) I write this code:

```
query = from x in ctx.livre
        select x;
livreBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

I added a column called Hierarchy to the dataGridView in order to add some informations (contained in a list) which are not in the table livre.

so I want to bind this list to that column Hierarchy

Example (without column `Hierarchy`):

```
query = from x in ctx.livre
        select x;
livreBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();


id | name

1 | name1

2  | name2
```

....

Example (with column Hierarchy):

```
query = from x in ctx.livre
        select x;
livreBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
//Some code here for binding list<string> to column Hierarchy

id | name | Hierarchy

1 | name1 | 1 is for name1

2  | name2 | this is second
```

....

How can I do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change your select to add the column in the linq?

like:

```
select new { x.id, x.name, Hierarchy = (x.id == 1 ? "1 is for name1" : "this is second") };
```

if the hierarchy data is in another list, you can just join to it and then reference

```
var result = from y in ctx.Livre
                     join h in hierList on y.id equals h.hierId
                     select new { y.id, y.name, Hierarchy = h.hierString };
```

Ok adding some code here to show the flattened hierarchy

```
public class Rayon
    {
        public int idLocation { get; set; }
        public string LocationName { get; set; }
        public List<Rayon> idParentLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Livre
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public List<Rayon> Location { get; set; }
    }

List<Rayon> library = new List<Rayon>();
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 1, idParentLocation = null, LocationName = "BookCase1" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 10, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase1")) }, LocationName = "1Shelf1" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 11, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase1")) }, LocationName = "1Shelf2" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 12, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase1")) }, LocationName = "1Shelf3" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 2, idParentLocation = null, LocationName = "BookCase2" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 20, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase2")) }, LocationName = "2Shelf1" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 21, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase2")) }, LocationName = "2Shelf2" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 22, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase2")) }, LocationName = "2Shelf3" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 3, idParentLocation = null, LocationName = "BookCase3" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 30, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase3")) }, LocationName = "3Shelf1" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 31, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase3")) }, LocationName = "3Shelf2" });
        library.Add(new Rayon() { idLocation = 32, idParentLocation = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.LocationName.Equals("BookCase3")) }, LocationName = "3Shelf3" });

        List<Livre> bkList = new List<Livre>();
        bkList.Add(new Livre() { id = 1, name = "Catch-22", author = "Heller", Location = new List<Rayon>() { library.Find(i => i.idLocation == 30) } });

        var test = bkList.SelectMany(b => b.Location.SelectMany(c => c.idParentLocation.Select(p => new { id = b.id, name = b.name, author = b.author, hierarchy = p.LocationName + "->" + c.LocationName + "->" + b.name })));
```

Comment: I don't have the `h.hierId and h.hierString`, how do you did it? @Kevin

Comment: What is the business rules for your hierarchy? If I knew the rules I could show you in code. Is there a parent column in the database?

Comment: I have a database _librairie_ which have 2 tables _livre_ and _rayon_ (shelf).
livre contain: #id, name, author, isbn, idRayon
rayon contain: idRayon, name, idParent (idParent is an idRayon)
I list all the table livre by: 
`query = from x in ctx.livre select x;


livreBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();`
So I want to add for each _livre_ its _rayon_ and its parents, so I add a function returns a list<string> (_hierarchy_) contain smth like that: "parent1_parent1_shelf1", "parent1_parent1_shelf2", ...
so I added a column to the dgv for adding the list to the dgv.
@Kevin

Comment: the datagridview will be like:
`1 | name1 | author1 | parent1->parent1->shelf1` \n <br>
`2 | name2 | author1 | parent1->parent3->shelf2`  
`3 | name3 | author2 | parent3->parent1->shelf1`  
`...`

**I am very sorry because I don't know how to do newline**

Comment: Are any of the references circular? I.E. id 1 has parent id 2 and id 2 has parent id 1?  that would cause problems with linq, otherwise I'll write up a query that will return the hierarchy

Comment: there is no circular reference, a child has only one parent, and a parent has several childs, a parent could have another parent (only one)

Comment: I did a function that return for each element _livre_ its shelf hierarchy then I add them to a list<string> (called hierList) . 
So I have now 2 list, one is for elements _livre_ `query.ToList()` and hierList, I want to merge them so I can display them . @Kevin

Comment: I edited the code to show the classes and how to show the hierarchy